# SonarQube doesn't detect rules with new pmd plugin

Tags: sonarqube, pmd, sonarqube-5.0

I am using SonarQube v 5.0.1 I have put my rules.xml file in extensions/rules/pmd directory.
Now everything works if i use  sonar-pmd-plugin version 2.3 - i start sonar, go to rules search and can find all the rules in rules.xml file.
But after switching to sonar-pmd-plugin version 2.4 i can't find my rules.
I have switched PMD version in older (v 2.3) plugin and it had no effect so i guess it's not PMD, it's the plugin. Has the default directory of rules changed with latest pmd plugin or something? Couldn't find anything in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with Sonarqube 4.5.5. Downgrading the sonar-pmd-plugin from 2.4 to 2.3 solved it. Now I can see the custom rules I put in extensions/rules/pmd.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue with Sonarqube 5.6.3 and the sonar-pmd-plugin 2.6. So, to see my custom rules I need to do the following:

- Put the ruleset definition jar file and the rules list xml file in the *extensions/rules/pmd* path, to do this I follow this [post](http://markmail.org/message/m7lwwnzy67i5ll3g).
- Downgrade the plugin to the 2.3 version.
- Add the custom rules in the **pmd.properties** file in the plugin, this files is in *org/sonar/l10n/*. 
  E.g.:

  ```
  #Add pmdAtgRules
  rule.pmd.ActionClassName.name=ActionClassName
  rule.pmd.BreaksLogging.name=BreaksLogging
  ```
- Restart Sonarqube.